# The ios simulator is showing me my elements misaligned

Tags: ios, c, xcode, simulator

I am a trainee in Objective C and Xcode. I don't know what is the reason because the iOS Simulator is showing me my elements misaligned.

Can someone help?

Here attach a picture 
http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=v7fhih&s=8#.VD8mvYuG-Ag

Comment: You are using xib, so check created xib is for iPad or iPhone.

Comment: Witch version xcode your using ? Are you using Auto layout

Comment: The version of xcode is 6.0.1. How do I put "Auto layout"?

Comment: @Batulla: Where do I check the created xib?